# Change values on several pages

Tags: text, widget-text

I'm building a catalog website that shows products, they are present on several pages and each time i want to change some details i have to enter to each page and change.
Is there any solutions to link this particular value to a variable that i can change it one time and affect on all the other pages.

Bests,
Amine

Comment: If you're using the Block Editor, make it a Reusable Block, and anytime you edit it, it will update everywhere.

Comment: i'm using wpbakery page builder

Comment: You could check to see if they support shortcodes. If so, you could add a custom shortcode that outputs specific info, and whenever you need to change it, change it once in code and it will update everywhere.